# Visual Studio Online TFS refuses to "source control" filenames starting with $

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops, visual-sourcesafe

**A bit of Background:**
I've migrated 3 old projects on a Win2003server to a Win2008R2 server (saying goodbye to IIS 6, VS2008, and Visual SourceSafe!). This Visual Studio 2012 solution with the 3 projects compiles and runs OK but I need to make some minor changes. Before I do much more, I am trying to add these projects to "source control" (TFS 14.0 with a local workspace). Two projects were added without problems. The 3rd project won't allow some items to be added to the team project folder and gives this message:

**TF10122: The path ‘$/MDW/MortgageDataWeb/MDS/$Common/$BuildNaviagator.asp’  contains a ‘$’ at the beginning of a path component. Remove the ‘$’ and try again.”**

The local path of this old classic ASP project is D:\Projects\MortgageDataWeb\MDS and one of the subfolders is named **$Common** and within that are dozens of files beginning with a **$** in the filename and the filetype is **.asp**.

I've done lots of research on this error message and I am deducing that the filenames and folder names in this project cannot begin with (nor contain??) any dollar signs. Most every explanation points at something about "Build Definitions" and Workflow 4.0 issues which I don't really understand.

The code was written about 9 years ago and I would be very reluctant to attempt global source code changes to hack out the offending $ from the item names.

Is there anything simple I could do to get this project added to TFS so I can move forward with my minor changes and be able to track things with TF version control? I'm not ready to need full-blown ALCM features (just want to view pending changes, check in, compare differences, etc.).

**Edit:**
Regarding versions of TFS, I followed advice from here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181475.aspx

Included there is a question about how to find version:

A: From a web browser and for an on-premises TFS, enter the following address:   `http://ServerName:8080/tfs/_home/About.`
For Visual Studio Online, enter the following address: `http://AccountName.visualstudio.com/_home/About`.

So, I did this on my development server and got this which looks like 14 to me:
[image]

Comment: FYI, there is no such thing as TFS 14.0.  There is TFS 2010 (aka 10.0), TFS 2012 (aka 11.0), and TFS 2013 (aka 12.0)

Comment: @Dylan Smith - please see the EDIT I added regarding how I got the 14.0 idea. Please tell me what I did wrong about that.

Comment: You're using Visual Studio Online, which isn't versioned -- it's just VSO.

Comment: Daniel, I admit some confusion here about TFS (I am new to this and perhaps you can see why I called it TFS 14.0 from EDIT above). Still, the essence of my question remains: Is there any way to add the folder above and the files contained within it to "source control"?

Comment: Delete my answer as I did not realized we were talking about VB6 era stuff. I fear you have no choice but changing the folder and file names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The message in the exception is correct.  Per [Naming Syntax, Conventions, and Limitations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245472(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Most names in Team Foundation version control cannot begin or end with spaces or tabs. Any character can be used for names or labels, except
>
> ...
>
> A dollar sign ($) cannot be the first character in a file name.

There is not a workaround.  You cannot place files with those names in TFVC.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. I have a folder beginning with a $ and many files within that begin with $. I am thinking of a renaming operation replacing $ with #, which I think is allowed. Nine years ago this naming convention seemed like a good idea at the time. Who knew..

Comment: It's funny that you mention using `#` instead; sometimes we have a desire for a completely private hierarchy of items...  when we do, we consider rooting it at `#`!  Interesting coincidence.  This was an interesting aside - we probably will never do this, and if we do, it will be completely hidden from the SDK and user-facing applications, you won't have to worry that suddenly your `#` paths will stop working.

(Sorry about the difficulties importing your existing files.)