# TFS ignores folders starting with $

Tags: tfs, version-control, ignore

I have an application that depends on a third party library where a file starts with sign '$'.

I have read about this issue, which is discussed in this thread [Visual Studio Online TFS refuses to "source control" filenames starting with $](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463171/visual-studio-online-tfs-refuses-to-source-control-filenames-starting-with)

Apparently there is no solution - but i really need a solution.

Does someone have a workarround to this or any ideas on how to solve it?

The thread is more than 2 years old so maybe something has changed that i do not know of :)

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, nothing has changed, and almost certainly this never will change.  Without knowing more about your configuration, I can't offer a workaround - a build step could copy or rename files into place, for example.

Comment: Thanks for replying. That is also what we might need to do. I have just written a detailed description on microsoft tfs support. Will update this ticket if i ever find a good workaround :D

Comment: That would be great - it would be interesting to know how you solve this.

Comment: Wow. So TFVC is unfit for purpose, by virtue of not accepting all possible filenames. That's really amazingly poorly thought out on MS' part. Why not switch to Git or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not changed.  Files and folders you add to Team Foundation version control must conform to the following restrictions:

[image]

*Source Link: [Version control files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/naming-restrictions#team-foundation-version-control)*

Files stating with `$` such as `$xxx.dll`  will auto change to `xxx.dll` when you checked in TFS source control.

In other words, you could not keep files stated with `$` characters in TFS source control system. If you force rename a file already in source control, you will get a pop up error such as below screenshot:

[image]

I'm afraid the only workaround is renaming the third party library file.

Comment: Sadly you are right. Just got this answer from microsoft tfs support: "Thank you for your feedback. There isn’t any workaround for this. TFS provides two version control system: TFVC and Git. If you use TFVC as source control, you could not include “$” in file name. Because TFVC use “$” as the start character of a source path. You could consider using Git as your version control system.". So it is confirmed that there exists no workaround to this problem other than what you suggest or making a script that copies the $XXX files to the correct places. Thanks though :)